# Wrap 2 blocks and show them on 1 line

Tags: php, html, wrapper

I have 2 blocks and they are one under another. I would want to display them side by side but my but my knowledge is weak.

```
{block name='product_flags_under'}
            {foreach $product.extraContent as $extra}
            {if $extra.moduleName=='ststickers'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/miniatures/sticker.tpl' stickers=$extra.content sticker_position=array(10,11,13) is_from_product_page=1}
            {/if}
            {/foreach}
            {hook h='displayUnderProductName'}            
          {/block}

{block name='product_reference'}
            {if $sttheme.display_pro_reference && isset($product.reference_to_display)}
              <div class="product-reference pro_extra_info flex_container">
                <span class="pro_extra_info_label">{l s='Reference' d='Shop.Theme.Panda'}: </span>
                <div class="pro_extra_info_content flex_child" {if $sttheme.google_rich_snippets} itemprop="sku" {/if}>{$product.reference_to_display}</div>
              </div>
            {/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do something like this. I have shown you one example. You can change the width percentage or remove them as your wish.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex
}
.left{
  width: 60%
}
.right{
  width: 40%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">    
 <div class="left">
   <p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </div>
 <div class="right">
      <p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can include your other element inside the left and right block

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your two blocks into another block, to wrap your blocks within a `div`. Then you can use `float` or `display: flex` to show both of your divs side by side.

Because it seems you can't add new blocks, you have to extend one block and delete the other. Here's an example:

**CSS**

```
.product-wrapper {
   display: flex;
}
```

**HTML**

```
{block name='product_flags_under'}
<div class="product-wrapper">
    {$smarty.block.parent}    
    {if $sttheme.display_pro_reference && isset($product.reference_to_display)}
        <div class="product-reference pro_extra_info flex_container">
            <span class="pro_extra_info_label">{l s='Reference' d='Shop.Theme.Panda'}: </span>
            <div class="pro_extra_info_content flex_child" {if $sttheme.google_rich_snippets} itemprop="sku" {/if}>{$product.reference_to_display}</div>
        </div>
    {/if}   
</div>
{/block}

{block name='product_reference'}{/block}
```

Comment: Hi Christopher Dosin, I tried with you code but something is wrong because with your code I get an error. Could you check if something is wrong with the code? I really tried different variants but my knowledge are so weak :(

Comment: I receive that error:  
SmartyCompilerException in smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php line 92:
Syntax error in template "/home/iskambg0/public_html/iskambgtest/themes/panda/templates/catalog/product/product-first.tpl" on line 92 "{block name='product_flags_under'}" - Unexpected "product_flags_under", expected one of: "}"

Comment: The whole error message you can see here: http://iskambg.com/iskambgtest/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8/939-1144-projekcionen-chasovnik.html#/32-%D1%86%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%BB

Comment: @DiyanDimitrov I edited my answer. It seems you're using a CMS or something like that. So you can't just add a new {block}  outside of an existing block. So you have to extend a block.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both your DIVs in a parent div then use flex to create a 2-column layout

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
  width: 45%;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

.col > div {border: 1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">    
    <div class="col"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="col"><div>2</div></div>
</div>
```